# How to efficiently fetch managed objects & index as dictionary by a key attribute?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsfetchrequest

So, I have an app where I'm importing some data from a web service and updating my local model to match. Entities from the web service have a uniquely identifying attribute, and I'm using that to figure out whether to create a new local object or fetch and update an existing one.

I know I don't want to loop through the input and run an `NSFetchRequest` searching for a match to each item's uniqueID, because fetch requests are expensive. Instead, I aggregate all the uniqueIDs from the input (easily done with `-[NSArray valueForKey:]`) and fetch all potentially existing objects using an IN predicate.

Then, I loop through the input -- for each item, I check to see whether the fetch I just did contains an object with matching unique ID. If it does, I update that object with new values from the input; otherwise I create a new object.

It's that matching which I'm not sure how to do efficiently. The fetch request gets me an array, so I need to search it to find the object matching the current input item's uniqueID. Right now I'm using `-[NSArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:]`... so I search the array again (for an object I know is in it) for each imported item.

It seems like the more concise and efficient way to do this would be to get the fetch request results as a dictionary, with unique IDs (that is, the attribute searched on in the predicate) as keys and the corresponding NSManagedObjects as values. I could set up such a dictionary from the result array, but that too would require searching the result array repeatedly.

If the kit provides something like this, I've not had much luck finding it. Anyone come across a good way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I feel dumb now. I was so focused on using the array of uniqueIDs I already had (and used in my fetch request) that I forgot I could work backwards.

So, here's the general outline:

1. Read in remote objects (array of dictionaries).
2. Extract from that an array of uniqueIDs (using `valueForKey:` as shorthand for looping through and filling an array from each dictionary's `objectForKey:`)
3. Use said array and an IN predicate to fetch potentially existing local objects.
4. Get an array of uniqueIDs corresponding to the fetch results by using `valueForKey:` on the result array.
5. Use `+[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:]` to get a dictionary mapping uniqueIDs to local NSManagedObjects.
6. Loop through remote objects, querying that dictionary to determine whether each has a corresponding local object that needs updating or something we need to make a new local object for.

In (simplified) code:

```
NSArray *remoteObjects; // array of dictionaries read in from server
NSArray *remoteIDs = [remoteObjects valueForKey:@"uniqueID"];
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:myEntityName];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"uniqueID IN %@", remoteIDs];
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:NULL];
NSArray *existingIDs = [results valueForKey:@"uniqueID"];
NSDictionary *existingObjects = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:results forKeys:existingIDs];
for (NSDictionary *remoteObject in remoteObjects) {
    MyManagedObject *existingObject = [existingObjects objectForKey:[remoteObject valueForKey:@"uniqueID"]];
    if (existingObject) {
        // have matching local object already, update it
    } else {
        // create new local object
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well instead of using arrays, you can use NSDictionary instead using the uniqueID as the key value.

Answer (score 0):

A bare bones starting point might look like:

```
NSArray *remoteObjects = // Array of dictionaries sorted by remotePrimarKey
NSArray *localObjects  = // Sorted by remotePrimaryKey using [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@", remoteKeys];

NSInteger localIndex  = 0;
NSInteger localCount  = [localObjects count];

MyManagedObject *localObject;

for (NSDictionary *remoteObject in remoteObjects) {

  localObject = nil;

  if (localIndex < localCount) {
    localObject = [localObjects objectAtIndex:localIndex];
  }

  if (<# localObject.primaryKey == remoteObject.primaryKey #>) {
    localIndex++;
  } else {
    localObject = // create new instance of MyManagedObject
  }

  // Configure localObject here
}
```

There a load of things you can change around and optimize but this is the clearest I could write it in the browser

In plain English

**Set up**

- Fetch the local objects sorted by the remotePrimaryKey and limited to the keys in the remote array
- Make sure the remote array is sorted by the same remotePrimaryKey

**Process**

- Step through the remote array one object at a time

  - If there is a local object then

    - Increment the index variable for the local array
    - Configure this locally returned object
  - If no local object found

    - Create a new object
    - Configure this new local object